# Why default does not work with double parentheses?

Tags: c#

Why this compiles:

```
return default(T);
```

but this does not:

```
return default((T));
```

The full method is

```
public static T PenultimateOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (items.Count() >= 2)
        return items.ElementAt(items.Count() - 2);
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

The errors for `default((T))` are

```
; expected
Invalid expression term ')'
Type expected
```

So it looks that parser is confued by double parentheses.

Comment: Why would you add unnecessary parentheses? Ever heard of casting?

Comment: No reason. I added it to see if it will work. Just it's interesting why it does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that's just not how the language is specified.

It's important to understand that `default` is like `typeof` - they're operators<sup>1</sup>, not method calls. It's not like the name of the type is an argument - it's an operand, and the operand is expected to just be the type name.

Section 7.6.13 of the C# 5 spec shows the construction of a default value expression:

> *default-value-expression:*
>     `default (` *type* `)`

where `type` is just the name of a type or type parameter. You can no more put parentheses round it here as you could when using a generic argument, or declaring a variable:

```
(string) x = ""; // Invalid
var x = new List<(string)>(); // Invalid
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's never specified as "the default operator" in the spec; always "default value expression" - but it really *is* an operator in all meaningful senses, and it's listed with the other operators in the precedence table.

Answer (score 8):

This is because `(AnyType)` (or in your case `(T)`) is expected to be a cast, so the parser gets confused about this and throws errors.

Comment: That can't be it. `default(` can never be followed by an expression, and what is the parser doing if it checks for casts in non-expressions?

Comment: @hvd It might treat it the same as an `object` method.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your comment doesn't make sense to me; I am probably missing your point.

Comment: It's not so much how the compiler actually parses it, as the fact that the operator isn't specified that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this compiles:

```
return default(T);
```

Because this is syntactically correct.

> but this does not:

```
return default((T));
```

Because this is not syntactically correct.